# Total dipole moment of three charge system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dipole

Consider three charges located on the $z$ axis: two $+q$ charges are located
at $\vec{r}=\pm{a}\hat{z}$ and the third charge of $−2q$ located at the origin. I am trying to find total dipole moment of all system but I think that it is zero since dipoles are pointing opposite direction. Just wanted to know if I am wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we consider its elementary definition(for the sake of convenience);
$$
\vec p=q\vec a
$$
which can give us the dipole moment of two point charges with $q$ charge on them and separated by a distance of $a$; we can derive the net dipole moment of the system. You can consider the point charge of $-2q$ as two $+q$ charge which will make the system consist of two dipoles(1-$±q$ charge at $(0,0,a)$ and $(0,0,0)$; 2-$±q$ charge at $(0,0,-a)$ and $(0,0,0)$:
$$
\vec p_1=q\vec a, \vec p_2=-q\vec a
$$
Since dipole moment obeys the superposition principle ($\vec p_{net}=\vec p_1+\vec p_2$);
$$
\vec p_{net}=q\vec a-q\vec a=0
$$
Therefore, the answer is yes. The magnitude of the net dipole moment vector is zero.

Comment: For completeness: but there will be a quadrupole moment $\sim qa^2$.

Comment: I searched but couldn t understand what quadropole moment. Can you explain or give me any link to work on?